# Creating user from php on active directory

Tags: php, windows, active-directory

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$ldapConn = ldap_connect('ldap://XXX.YYY.WWW.NNN:389');
ldap_set_option($ldapConn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

ldap_bind( $ldapConn, 'CN=Administrador,CN=Users,DC=XXX,DC=YYY', 'PASWD');

$dn_user='CN=testLDAP,OU=empleados,OU=usuarios_XXX,DC=XXX,DC=YYY';;

$ldaprecord['cn'] = "testLDAP";
$ldaprecord['givenName'] = "testLDAP";  
$ldaprecord['sn'] = "testLDAP";
$ldaprecord['sAMAccountName'] = "testLDAP";
$ldaprecord['UserPrincipalName'] = "testLDAP@XXX.com";
$ldaprecord['displayName'] = "testLDAP";
$ldaprecord['name'] = "testLDAP";
$ldaprecord['UserAccountControl'] = "544";
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][0] = 'top';
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][1] = 'person';
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][2] = 'organizationalPerson';
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][2] = 'user';
$ldaprecord['mail'] = "lkl@fh.com";

ldap_add($ldapConn, $dn_user, $ldaprecord);
ldap_unbind($ldapConn);  
?>
```

With this code I can create a user on Active Directory , but if I use "Active Directory Users" MMC to locate the user created by this script, I can´t see this user on the OU where I created it, but  I can see it from ADSI Edit in the same OU where I can´t see it in "Active Directory Users" MMC, I can search the user in the search option located in  the in "Active Directory Users" MMC.

Also I can´t login with user as regular user (setting password manually)

Could it be a mistake or missing property in the ldaprecord?

Comment: Yes it could be a mistake or a missing property. Why do you ask? You had a specific mistake or property in mind? Which properties you know of do have to exist? Can you provide a list an examples how how a correct user must look like? And how does your user look like?

Comment: I don´t know where is the mistake o missing property,and my question is about this.
I can´t provide how a correct user must look like o which propierties has, because I don´t know.

Comment: So how did your wrote that code then? By guessing?

Comment: Not really, I known some of parameters and structure but not all, I´m looking for some that run something similar and know where is the mistake.

Comment: Well, I highly suggest you ask about the specification first. Not that you could read out the specs from working code, too, but it's more straight forward to ask about something concrete (existing) and not about "mistakes" which are largely undefined (especially if not obviously, like probably just a missing parameter your setup requires but not anybody else one).

Comment: I know specification of the object user, but there is nothing about how to show it on "Active Directory Users" MMC or not.

I compare with ADSI edit a normal user with user created with this code and the mandatory propierties of the object are ok, the extended propierties are ok too.
 
I don´t know were is the mistake , probably is not documented, es un bug or I doing something wrong, as I told i´m looking for anyone with the same error.

Comment: Okay, that sounds really wired. Can you show the dump of the PHP created user and of the other user - just for reference? And probably that user needs to be registered somewhere else to appear in the MMC listing?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying again and now it works I don´t know really why.
I suspect is any problem in the mmc console, the code is the same and it works without problem.